# Creating list of lists from nested dictionary values (tree)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, nested

I have used hierarchical clustering to create a tree of clusters.

This results in:

```
dic = {6: {2: 2, 5: {3: 3, 4: {0: 0, 1: 1}}}}
```

lists in list according to clusters:

```
[ [[6]],
  [[2], [5]],
  [[2], [3], [4]],
  [[2], [3], [0], [1]] ]
```

lists in list according to values:

```
[ [[2, 3, 0, 1]],
  [[2], [3, 0, 1]],
  [[2], [3], [0, 1]],
  [[2], [3], [0], [1]] ]
```

What I want to end up with is 'lists in list according to values'.

Thanks

Comment: You want to end up with the 4 lists or just the first or last one?

Comment: @kubatucka I want to end up with whole list of lists as shown in the last code block.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flat` flattens input array
`walk` recursively walks tree and unpacks values

final list comprehension that generates array same length as number of values extracted
each array element is an array with x single value arrays from l (`l[i:i+1]`) concatenated with array slice of rest of elements in l (`l[x:]`)

```py
dic = {6: {2: 2, 5: {3: 3, 4: {0: 0, 1: 1}}}}
flat = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
walk = lambda node: flat([walk(v) if type(v) is dict else [v] for v in node.values()])

l = walk(dic)
print([[l[i:i+1] for i in range(x)]+[l[x:]] for x in range(len(l))])
```

Answer (score 1):

I just spent way too much time for this:

```
def list_of_list(d):
    if type(d)!=dict:
        return [[[d]]]
    results=[]
    for k,value in d.items():
        results.append(list_of_list(value))
    L=len(max(results,key=len))
    for i in range(len(results)):
        j=len(results[i]) 
        results[i].extend([results[i][j-1]]*(L-j))
    outputtop=[v  for result in results for v in result[0][0]]
    output=[[outputtop]]
    for l in range(L):
        output.append([ val  for result in results for  val in result[l]])
    return output
```

Comment: I'm sorry it took long, thank you very much I'm really happy with this!